# Database connection error while instaling informatica server 9.6 on windows 10

Tags: database, connection, informatica

I m getting error while trying to install the informatica 9.6 on windows 10
on step 5b of 8
the SQL developer works fine however, I am not able to move ahead with the same details to complete the server setup. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEByU.png)

Comment: Could you please check 1. if you can connect to DB from Win 10 using `sqlplus`? 2. Can you please check if all entries like user, password are correct.3. you have proper drivers/JAVA version installed?

Comment: Can you also paste the error text into your question?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect the SQL Plus and SQL Developer also. The connections details are fine. Please see the Screenshot attached in the question.

Comment: Hi - given that your screenshot is showing "XE", are you using Oracle Express Edition? If you are, do you know if that is supported as I'm pretty sure it isn't?